# Scroll event not getting detected in simple example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-events

Following simple example I am not getting alerts, can someone help me out?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    alert("Hi!");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting "Hi!" to alert up, whenever I scroll on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, you just need to have some content in the `body` that's taller than the window so that the page will actually scroll:

```css
div { height: 2000px; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        alert("Hi!");
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>Some content...</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add height to the body

`body{
height:1200px;
}`

Then try this

`$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    alert('Hi');
});`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need content on your page for it to work. Right now it doesn't 'see' your window

Answer (score 0):

It is very normal because the scroll event is not called. Your body should be tall enough to allow the scrolling event. In your code, you have no content yet. Try adding some content with large `height`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        alert("Hi!");
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br>Scroll now<br></div>
</body>

</html>
```